# Send Outlook email contents to asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have created outlook addin button in the file menu of outlook.  When I click it I want to send the details of the email (such as subject, body, and attachments) to an asp.net web page.

I am able to access the email contents through c# code.  What do I need to do to determine if the information came through my add in or some other source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it to a temp file and read it from there. Add a keyword in the temp file which would identify that it came from your addin app. You can check for the presence of this keyword to make sure that it is your addin that is supplying the contents of the webpage.